# graph of functions of several variables

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Frequently, we are given a two variables function $f(x, y)$ and we are asked to draw the graph $f(x,y)=c$ where $c$ is a constant. The graph $f(x,y)=c$ is a curve in three-dimensional space or a curve in $xy$-plane? How can we know which curve the question want?

Also, if we are asked to draw the graph of the function $g(x)=f(x, y_0)$, then the graph of the function is a curve in three-dimensional space or or a curve in $xy$-plane? How can we know which curve the question want?

Comment: $f(x,y)=c$ is a curve in xy-plane. The graph of $g(x)$ is in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Answer (score 1):

The function $f$ takes points in $\mathbb{R}^2$ to numbers in $\mathbb{R}$. So the most common way to visualize this is to make the graph where the $xy$ plane is the domain and $z$ axis is the range. So for each point in the $xy$ plane you plot the points $(x, y, f(x, y))$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Since $f$ is constant, the graph will be just a plane.

This way of graphing is similar to what you encounter for single variable functions where you plot the points $(x, f(x))$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$. The second function $g(x) = f(x, y_0)$ should be graphed in this way. You have to plot the points $(x, g(x)) = (x, f(x, y_0))$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ for each $x$. Note that $y_0$ is some fixed number and you are only changing values of $x$.